# problem in the input text into an EditText

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

i was creating my app login page.
I have a problem with the edittext because the input text is outside the edittext frame. how can i solve?

[image: application editText result]

this is my EditText background code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<corners android:radius="20dp"/>
<stroke android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#D3D3D3"/>
</shape>
```

and this my EditText xml

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/usernameText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias=".3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".5"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:inputType="text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:autofillHints="   Password"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/usernameText"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.153"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add padding to your background drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#D3D3D3"/>
    <padding android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"/>
</shape>
```